# url.openConnection() fails

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am at my wits' end as I am trying to create a bitmap out of a URL and display it on an ImageView, but everything I try fails miserably.

Here is my code:

```
mPictureView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_picture);
String pictureToShowPath = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_PICTURE);

//The URL is http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Buddha_statue.jpg
URL url = new URL(pictureToShowPath);

//I also tried with BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent())
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); 

mPictureView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This code is inside a try block. At `url.openConnection().getInputStream()` a null exception is thrown, therefore the bitmap is never created. The exception is null so I don't even know which kind of exception it is. 
I have tested this code both on my phone with KitKat and my tablet with Nougat, and it works on none of them. My devices are connected to WiFi and the app requests these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I have tried other methods to download the image first, like using `HttpURLConnection` or a `BufferedInputStream` with a URL, and the problem always seems to be the same: every time a connection is attempted a null exception is thrown.

Comment: use picasso / glide for image loading.. it will perform background operation for fetching and display on your imageview

Comment: if you want i can show you the link

Comment: why don't you use any library ? like picasso or glide?

Comment: @SantanuSur thanks for the suggestion, I have used Picasso and I got a similar problem. I will try with Glide.